# Incluir dois laços while em uma estrutura jQuery para o jogo JokenPô

Tags: javascript, jquery

[image]
                Primeira tela - Inserção do nome do usuário

[image]Segunda tela - Usuário clica na imagem correspondente a opção e dai é feita a comparação

Eu quero colocar dois laços while. O primeiro laço while é para caso haja empate. Se houver, é necessário que o usuário Marcos escolha uma outra opção: Pedra, Papel ou Tesoura e o computador gere uma nova opção, enquanto houver empate o laço continuará.

O segundo laço é para gerar uma rodada de até 3 pontos. No caso se o jogador Marcos conseguir 3 pontos primeiros encerra a partida, ou o computador.

Código do programa

```
    $(document).ready(function(){

    var choice = null;  
    var vitoriaPlayer = 0;
    var vitoriaComputer = 0;


    //Altera o nome do jogador no inicio do index_game
    $("#nameUser").text(localStorage.jogador);

    //Gera a opção do computador
    var computerChoice = Math.random();

    if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
        computerChoice = "Pedra";

    }else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
        computerChoice = "Papel";

    }else {
        computerChoice = "Tesoura";

    } 

    //Evento e função responsáveis por comparar as jogadas e mostrar para o usuário
    $('#pedra, #papel, #tesoura').on('click', function(ev){

        //Atribui o valor clicado pelo usuário para variavel choice
        var choice = $(this).prop("id").toLowerCase(); 
        computerChoice = computerChoice.toLowerCase();

        if((computerChoice == choice) || (computerChoice == choice)||(computerChoice == choice)){
                $("#vencedor").text("Empate");
                $("#jogada-jogador").text("Jogada do jogador(a) "+localStorage.jogador+" foi "+choice);
                $("#jogada-oponente").text("Jogada do oponente foi "+computerChoice);

        }else if (choice === "pedra"){

                if (computerChoice === "tesoura"){
                    $("#vencedor").text("Jogador "+localStorage.jogador+" venceu");

                    vitoriaPlayer += 1;

                    $("#scoreUser").text(vitoriaPlayer);

                    $("#jogada-jogador").text("Jogada do jogador(a) "+localStorage.jogador+" foi "+choice);
                    $("#jogada-oponente").text("Jogada do oponente foi "+computerChoice);


        }else{
                    $("#vencedor").text("Oponente venceu");

                    vitoriaComputer += 1;

                    $("#scoreOponent").text(vitoriaComputer);

                    $("#jogada-jogador").text("Jogada do jogador(a) "+localStorage.jogador+" foi "+choice);
                    $("#jogada-oponente").text("Jogada do oponente foi "+computerChoice);
            }

        }else if (choice === "papel"){
                if (computerChoice === "pedra"){

                     $("#vencedor").text("Jogador "+localStorage.jogador+" venceu");

                     vitoriaPlayer += 1;
                     $("#scoreUser").text(vitoriaPlayer);

                     $("#jogada-jogador").text("Jogada do jogador(a) "+localStorage.jogador+" foi "+choice);
                     $("#jogada-oponente").text("Jogada do oponente foi "+computerChoice);

        }else{
                     $("#vencedor").text("Oponente venceu");

                     vitoriaComputer += 1;

                     $("#scoreOponent").text(vitoriaComputer);

                     $("#jogada-jogador").text("Jogada do jogador(a) "+localStorage.jogador+" foi "+choice);
                     $("#jogada-oponente").text("Jogada do oponente foi "+computerChoice);

            }

        }else if (choice === "tesoura") {

                if (computerChoice === "pedra"){
                     $("#vencedor").text("Oponente venceu");

                     vitoriaComputer += 1;

                     $("#scoreOponent").text(vitoriaComputer);

                     $("#jogada-jogador").text("Jogada do jogador(a) "+localStorage.jogador+" foi "+choice);
                     $("#jogada-oponente").text("Jogada do oponente foi "+computerChoice);

        }else{

                     $("#vencedor").text("Jogador "+localStorage.jogador+" venceu");

                     vitoriaPlayer += 1;

                     $("#scoreUser").text(vitoriaPlayer);

                     $("#jogada-jogador").text("Jogada do jogador(a) "+localStorage.jogador+" foi "+choice);
                     $("#jogada-oponente").text("Jogada do oponente foi "+computerChoice);
            }


        }

        //Janela modal
        ev.preventDefault();

        var id = $("a[rel=modal]").attr("href");

        var alturaTela = $(document).height();
        var larguraTela = $(window).width();

        //Colocando o fundo preto
        $('#mascara').css({'width':larguraTela,'height':alturaTela});
        $('#mascara').fadeIn(1000); 
        $('#mascara').fadeTo("slow",0.8);

        var left = ($(window).width() /2) - ( $(id).width() / 2 );
        var top = $(window).scrollTop()+10

        $(id).css({'top':top,'left':left});
        $(id).show();   

        });

        $("#mascara").click( function(){
            $(this).hide();
            $(".window").hide();
        });

        $('.fechar').click(function(ev){
            ev.preventDefault();
            $("#mascara").hide();
            $(".window").hide();
            });
        });
```

Tentativa - Code pen

```
             function bot(){
             //Gera a opção do computador
                 var computerChoice = Math.random();

                 if (computerChoice < 0.34) {
                     computerChoice = "pedra";

                 }else if(computerChoice <= 0.67) {
                     computerChoice = "papel";

                 }else {
                     computerChoice = "tesoura";

                } 
             }

               $("#txtBoxValue").focusout(function(){
              var cont = 0;  
              var b = null;
              var a = $(this).val();

              b = bot();
              while(a === b){
                   console.log("empate")
                   cont+=1
                   console.log(cont);
                   if(cont >=5){
                      break;
                }

            }
   });

  });
```

Comment: Que tal por um [mcve]?

Comment: Pronto, me desculpe, eu esqueci de colocar o exemplo que tava rodando.